# pyinstaller module not found error, can't fix

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Whenever I try to compile my program, the modules are never found.
[Missing modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39fuI.png)

Here is the code I'm running, inside pycharm, inside the venv:

```
pyinstaller --paths=C:\Users\gummi\Desktop\BazaarBot/venv/Lib/site-packages main.py
```

How can I get this to compile with no erros?

Error:

```
missing module named customtkinter - imported by C:\Users\gummi\Desktop\BazaarBot\main.py (top-level)
missing module named pynput - imported by C:\Users\gummi\Desktop\BazaarBot\main.py (top-level)
missing module named pyautogui - imported by C:\Users\gummi\Desktop\BazaarBot\main.py (top-level), bazaa
```

Comment: Enough information to solve the problem and test answers needs to be included **in the text of the question itself**. A question that isn't answerable without following links isn't complying with [MRE] rules.

Comment: Also, error messages need to be included as text, not screenshots. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Are those modules installed _inside the venv_?

Comment: The modules are installed inside the venv. I've edited the original post to incude the error.

Comment: create a [mre]. Or you can try reading the [pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix my issue by running the venv in cmd instead of in pycharm, and ensuring once again that all the modules I imported were installed in the venv. On top of this, there was still a long list of module not found errors for modules which I had not imported, but after compiling these didn't seem to affect the program at all.